# How long does an SQL SESSION statement last?

Tags: php, mysql

If in PHP I do this:

```
mysql_query("SET SESSION sql_mode=''");
```

When does the 'session' end? Is it when I do

```
mysql_close($connection);
```

or after a certain amount of time (eg 1440 seconds)?

Comment: mysql_close Closes ur SESSION to mysql. but if ur script is releasing the .pid. thats something i cant tell. but ur session is closed the second u run mysql_close. btw try to use mysqli_ instead of mysql_ :)

Comment: I would expect this to be trivial to test and figure out.

Answer (score 0):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html

> There are two scopes in which system variables exist. Global
>   variables affect the overall operation of the server. Session
>   variables affect its operation for individual client connections. A
>   given system variable can have both a global and a session value.

So regardless of how the connection is closed, the variable's value would be reset upon a new connection as a session value only persists for that specific connection.

Comment: Thanks, I'd just never come across it before and couldn't find an easy way to find out how long it lasts.